# How to position a widget in a Stack based on coordinates flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

My question is simple. Lets say i have an offset value of (128.2, 324.9) which is the coordinates of a position in a stack. How can i a position a widget in the stack targetting this offset value. I currently have my `GestureDetector` class giving me this coordinates value but i want to also add a widget tin that position dynamically.

```
Widget addIndicatorImage(Offset offset) {
    if(_tapPosition!=null){
      return Positioned(child:
      new Image.asset('images/pain_report_indicator.png',
        height: 32, width: 32,));
    }else{
      return Container();
    }

  }

 Stack(
                children: [
                  GestureDetector(
                    onTapDown: _handleTapDown,
                    onTap: () {

                    },
                    child: Container(
                        child: Image.asset(
                      images[index],
                      height: 500,
                      width: double.infinity,
                    )),
                  ),
                  addIndicatorImage(_tapPosition),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
```

Comment: check `Positioned` widget

Comment: what parameters do i pass for the offset inside positioned widget

Answer (score 3):

#### Example

`Center` is used to allow the `Stack` to fill the most space it can, constrained by its parent, otherwise `Stack` tries to size itself to its contents (if I remember correctly).

The `Container` between `Center` and `Stack` is added only for (copy/pasting) illustration to show the dimensions / border of the Stack.  This widget isn't needed.

The `Positioned` widget would normally take two arguments, an `X` and a `Y`. But, the somewhat confusing part is that it doesn't automatically use the top left corner of your child.  Instead you choose which sides of your child you wish to offset from its respective side of the `Stack`.  See the comments in code below.  You could use `right:` and `bottom:` for example instead of `top:` and `left:`

```
class StackPositionedExample extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          border: Border.all(width: 5, color: Colors.lightGreenAccent)
        ),
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            Positioned(
              left: 50, // distance between this child's left edge & left edge of stack
              top: 150, // distance between this child's top edge & top edge of stack
              child: Container(
                height: 100,
                width: 100,
                color: Colors.blue,
                alignment: Alignment.center,
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Positioned Widget to change the position of your widget as you like giving it top, right, bottom, left coordinates
you can also use height and width to change the size of widget.

simply wrap the widget in this case the container as shown

```
Positioned(
      left:128.2,
      top: 324.9,
      child: Container(
                  child: Image.asset(
                  mages[index],
                  eight: 500,
                  width: double.infinity,
                    ),
                   ),
                  ),
                  addIndicatorImage(_tapPosition),
                  ),

),
```